# Create HTML table with PHP foreach

Tags: php, html, foreach

My table is messed when I tried to create the HTML table . Here is my code.

```
$data['items'] = array(
array(
    'des' => 'item #1', 
    'price' => 10, 
    'o' => 2, 
    't' => 15, 
    ), 
array(
    'des' => 'item #3', 
    'price' => 11, 
    'o' => 4, 
    't' => 10, 
    ), 
);
```

Here is my proceed to create the table. But it seems totally wrong. Specially the condition checking in foreach in the tr and td...

```
<table><thead align="left" style="display: table-header-group"><tr><th>
    <table><tr> <td>col 1 </td>
                <td>col 2 </td>
                <td>col 3 </td>
                <td>col 4 </td>
                <td>col 5 </td>

    </tr></table>
</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($data['items'] as $rows) :?>
    <tr class="item_row">
            <?php 
            $total = 0;
            foreach ($rows as $key => $value) : ?>
            <td><?php echo $key+1 ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $value['description'] ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $value['price'] ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $value['o'] ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $value['t'] ?></td>
            <?php endforeach;?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The problem I am facing firstly the condition is not right, so at every row it just priting the first value every time. 
secondly, obviously the table broke.
 Need some help to solve this problem.

Comment: "Need some help to solve this problem" What problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a loop too many, the inner loop is not necessary and causes warnings as `$value` is not an array.

Apart from that, you have messed up your table head, adding another table and `th` tags where they are not necessary.

You need something like:

```
<table>
  <thead align="left" style="display: table-header-group">
  <tr>
     <th>col 1 </th>
     <th>col 2 </th>
     <th>col 3 </th>
     <th>col 4 </th>
     <th>col 5 </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
$total = 0;
foreach ($data['items'] as $rows) :?>
  <tr class="item_row">
        <td><?php echo ++$total; ?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $rows['description']; ?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $rows['price']; ?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $rows['o']; ?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $rows['t']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: looks to me the closing tag for the foreach is in the wrong place or am I wrong?

Comment: @Robert Definitely, thanks.

Comment: prego ("you welcome" in Italian) One kind curiosity: do you kindly know when (since which version of "what") it has been introduced the ":" short tag? I mean this is something I have discovered this winter, before I was making PHP to print all the table tags. This is pretty cleaner and shorter

Comment: @Robert Personally I am not a fan, but I rarely mix php and html anymore. It seems it has been possible for a long time: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php